# Semi colon in between a sql query in Oracle

Tags: sql, oracle

The 2 sample query below yields 2 different output in Oracle database, please help me understand the difference of such a behaviour of the queries.
Also, if anyone can elaborate on usage/syntax of a semi-colon (;) in between a query. Thanks

1.

```
select * from db.ci_customer c
where c.char_type_cd = 'BIRTHDATE' ; and c.per_id = '0226151234'
```

2. 

```sql
select * from db.ci_customer c
where c.char_type_cd = 'BIRTHDATE' and c.per_id = '0226151234'
```

Comment: `;` ends the query. So `and c.per_id = '0226151234'` is not included in your first example

Answer (score 2):

`;` is a statement terminator and, as the name suggests, will terminate (end) a statement.

Therefore if you have the script:

```sql
select * from db.ci_customer c where c.char_type_cd = 'BIRTHDATE' ; and c.per_id = '0226151234'

select * from db.ci_customer c where c.char_type_cd = 'BIRTHDATE' and c.per_id = '0226151234'
```

Then the first statement is from the first character until the first `;`, which is:

```sql
select * from db.ci_customer c where c.char_type_cd = 'BIRTHDATE'
```

and does not include the `per_id` filter.

The second statement is from after the first `;` until either the next `;` or the end of the script:

```sql
 and c.per_id = '0226151234'

select * from db.ci_customer c where c.char_type_cd = 'BIRTHDATE' and c.per_id = '0226151234'
```

Which is an invalid SQL statement and will raise a syntax error (if you run the worksheet as a script using <kbd>F5</kbd> in SQL Developer).